# Area of a quadrilateral inside a right angled triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, quadrilateral

Can we find the area of the quadrilateral in terms of the length $AB$? Let's denote the length $AB$ as the variable $x$.

[image: picture of triangle]

I tried to use the triangle similarity to compare triangle $CEF$ and $CBA$ but I am stuck here. What other tools do I need to use to find the area of quadrilateral $BDEF$ in terms of the length $AB$?

How do we prove that the area is $$f(x)=6 - \frac 8x - \frac{x^2} 4$$

Comment: It seems that we need other information. If the area of $\triangle{ABC}$ was $4$, then we would get the answer you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Let $BC=y$.

Thus, since $$\frac{EF}{AB}=\frac{CE}{BC},$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{EF}{x}=\frac{2}{y},$$ which gives $$EF=\frac{2x}{y}$$ and
$$S_{BEFD}=\frac{\left(\frac{2x}{y}+2-x\right)(y-2)}{2}.$$
We see that the area  depends on $y$.

Comment: Can we define y in terms of x?

Comment: No, because $y$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: For example y^2 + x^2 = AC^2

Comment: But $AC$ is not given

Comment: Im thinking we could use the fact that AD=2 and start something from that

Comment: @Han Sen I used. We need something more. If $y\rightarrow+\infty$ so the area is closed to $+\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing the line perpendicular to AB which passes through F and denote its intersection with AB as G. This gives you another triangle, FGA which is similar to CEF and CBA.

Comment: But i saw that this triangle Does not give us any new insight towards this problem